# The /questions/{id}/linked method is returning extra questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v1.1, linked-questions

Consider the following question on ServerFault:

https://serverfault.com/questions/45734/the-coolest-server-names

Linked questions:

[image]

Note that there's only two listed. However, querying:

http://api.serverfault.com/1.1/questions/45734/linked

Yields:

```
{
  "total": 32,
  "page": 1,
  "pagesize": 30,
  "questions": [
  ...
```

Where did all of the extra linked questions come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another subtle one, boiled down to a bogus boolean clause accidentally including related  (rather than explicitly linked) questions some of the time.

Fixed now.